# There are lines in the notifications in Lubuntu 14.10. (See image below) What's wrong?

Tags: lubuntu, notification

I'm using Dell Vostro 3446, Lubuntu 14.10, 64-bit. It's a completely clean installation. No problems in the installation. But, the notifications have lines in them, and aren't "clear" like it used to be in 14.04

[image]

1. I haven't installed any external video drives yet. Could that be the problem?

or

2. Will this be fixed with xcompmgr or Compiz?

Comment: I see the same thing if I use the default gtk theme: /usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default. It didn't happen in 14.04. Mine is a Dell laptop (integrated Intel graphics).

Comment: Does changing the theme fix it, then? Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using Greybird which you can get by installing shimmer-themes from the software center.

Comment: I think you should report it here by signing up: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/lubuntu-users

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-notifyd/+bug/1362555 with a workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1362555

My command:
`sudo rm -f /usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/images/panel-bg.png`

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed now : 
http://lubuntublog.blogspot.ch/2015/05/notifications-fixed.html